# R Character classes

Tags: r, regex

Could anybody explain why "aba12" shows up, when I have specified `{2}`?

```
strings=c("Ab12","aba12","BA12","A 12b","B!","d", "  ab")

grep("^[[:alpha:]]{2}", strings, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: Because "aba12" starts with 2 alpha character. Did you also want to make sure the third character was not an alpha character or something?

Comment: I would like to select strings, starting with a alpha character and contains max 2 alpha characters. How is this done?

Comment: Also, in explanation of the behavior of `^[[:alpha:]]{2}`, that statement tells the Regex engine to match the beginning of the string, then *exactly* two ASCII A-Z/a-z characters. It asserts nothing about the remainder of the string. Regex will process the remainder of the string, but there is no remaining criteria to match, hence the need for the solution posted by @Frank.

Answer (score 3):

You can use ...

```
grep("^[[:alpha:]]{2}[^[:alpha:]]", strings, value=TRUE)

# [1] "Ab12" "BA12"
```

`[...]` enumerates accepted characters and `[^...]` negates it. Further, from @Mako212:

> `^[[:alpha:]]{2}` [...] tells the Regex engine to match the beginning of the string, then exactly two ASCII A-Z/a-z characters. It asserts nothing about the remainder of the string. Regex will process the remainder of the string, but there is no remaining criteria to match

My answer above expects a non-alpha character following the initial two. From MrFlick's comment:

> If you also want to match "AB", then use
>
> ```
> grep("^[[:alpha:]]{2}([^[:alpha:]]|$)", strings, value=TRUE)
> ```
>
> to match a non-alpha character or end of string.

Comment: If you also want to match "AB" (which seems to be in the spirit of the request), then use `grep("^[[:alpha:]]{2}([^[:alpha:]]|$)", strings, value=TRUE)` to match a non-alpha character or end of string.

Comment: Thank you, Frank & MrFlick!